# video renders well on mac, but has bizarre effect on windows

Tags: video

I have been editing a video which has rendered fine up until recently, I had it in a .mp4 format on a windows machine editing using wevideo, and I sent it to my friend who edited it on a mac, I think using aftereffects, and converted it to a .mov and now it has this strange effect, but only when I download it to the local machine (by the way the black bars are fine, what I am confused about are the horizontal lines):

before:
[image: Before:]

on my phone after:

[image]

on my computer after:

[image]

What could be going on and how should I fix it?

thanks!

Comment: Wrong encode settings? See @JohnManly's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those horizontal lines you're seeing are what you would call `Interlacing` and it's usually done in an attempt to increase a video's frame rate without using more bandwidth (in other words, make it play smoother and take up less space).  You can easily get rid of this by running your video through a program like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) and using their "Decomb" filter.

There are other, more advanced methods to clean this up as well.

I personally use [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) and I've read that you can even do it in [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), but I think handbrake is the quickest and easiest way to accomplish deinterlacing your video.

Comment: @nosyarg instead of encoding the video again thus loosing more detail and quality you should tell your friend to pick a better output format, **progressive** instead of interlaced if possible. While most programs should be able to detect interlaced content and display it without combing, interlacing remains a crude hack from the CRT era. AFAIK interlaced formats have been dropped with the move to UHD.